# Why are exclusiveMinimum and exclusiveMaximum keywords needed in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Instead of writing

```
{
  "type": "number",
  "minimum": 0,
  "maximum": 100,
  "exclusiveMaximum": true
}
```

why can't we write ?

```
{
  "type": "number",
  "minimum": 0,
  "maximum": 101
}
```

I understand the first one gives the better readability in terms of range for any checks(ex. temperature, height etc... ), but 2nd one will get the job done.

Is there any other specific purpose ?

**UPDATE: blex and jfriend00 responses make the context clear for usage and makes sense on why those keywords would come handy when defining a schema**

**Is there any way i can close this question now ?**

Comment: If you're only dealing with integers, it does not matter. But if you're dealing with floats, writing `100` and setting `exclusiveMaximum` might be better than writing `99.999999...`. But anyway, there are no fixed rules for structuring your JSON. Just make it as easy to process as you can to suit your needs.

Comment: it depends on your purpose. please explain, what you like to do with it.

Comment: needed in JSON? I really don't get it

Comment: This has nothing more to do with JSON than a spelling error has to do with a word processor.

Comment: You have to be more accurate to get a good answer.

Comment: There's clearly some context you've left out of your question.  What is the JSON file being used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a [generic format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and you can specify either of your two formats as legal JSON.  So, your question is not really about JSON at all.

What I assume is that you're being asked to provide a specific set of fields to some other function that takes this as parameters.  In that case, the need for the `exclusiveMaximum` parameter would be entirely about how the consumer of this set of parameters is using it and you'd have to look into the details of that specific library to see exactly why one or the other is better.

Likely, the difference is whether the boundary number is allowed or not (if integers) and if floating point numbers are allowed whether the intervening floating point numbers are allowed or not.

There is a proposed JSON validation scheme described [here](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor17) that provides some explanation of maximum and exclusiveMaximum.  In that proposed specification, it describes exclusiveMaximum as optional so again, it would depend entirely on what code is using this validation scheme on whether it is required or not (something you have not shared with us).

In [this particular reference](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/Maximum-and-exclusivemaximum) on the JSON validation scheme, it says this:

> If maximum is present but not `exclusiveMaximum`, it MAY be considered
>   that the `exclusiveMaximum` keyword value is boolean false.

This implies that you are not required to specify `exclusiveMaximum` if everyone is following the specification.

For more help, please tell us exactly what you're using this data structure for and what library is consuming it.